# Select an element with empty class attribute (class="") using CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS way to select an element that looks like that by class?

```
<a class="" href="...">
```

Like a selector for empty class declarations?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use element-attribute selector here with an empty class value

```
div[class=""] {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/h94Df/)

Note: You can replace the `div` with required element

Comment: @e1che Good :) and glad it was useful and user1856596 you welcome :)

Comment: That edit was probably because your answer doesn't match the question. In future, just stick to answering the question based on the code that is given.

Answer (score 34):

Provided the `class` attribute is present as you say you can use the attribute selector like this:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/87Wd7/)

```
<a class="" href="...">asd</a>

a[class=""] {
    color: red;
}
```

If you want this to work when there is no `class` attribute present on the element you can use `:not([class])`.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/87Wd7/2/)

```
<a href="...">asd</a>

a:not([class]) {
    color: red;
}
```

These can then be combined together to handle both cases.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/87Wd7/2/)

```
<a href="...">asd</a>
<a class="" href="...">asd</a>

a[class=""],
a:not([class]) {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: This one worked, markup had no class and I couldn't change it, thanks.

Comment: The ":not([class])" solution is the best answer!