# applying css which have no class

Tags: css

I want to apply the css only for the headings h2 which have no class. There are different classes with some h2 and some h2 has no class.

I have tried like this:

```
h2[class*=""]{
  background: #cccccc;
}
```

But seems it's not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
h2:not([class]){
  background: #cccccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will apply css to all `h2` elements that do not have a class:

```
h2:not([class]) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple actually. Try

```
h2
{
//css here
}
```

**EDIT**

For applying this for ONLY elements without classes, [you have your answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353893/select-an-element-with-empty-class-attribute-class-using-css)

The problem in your code is that asterisk.

Comment: That adds the CSS to all h2 elements, including those which already have a class assigned.

Comment: @CalvinScherle You're right. I might have misunderstood the question, i edited my answer.

Comment: You might want to note that the answer in your provided link only works if the `class` attribute is present. If the element has no class attribute at all, then that won't work either (not sure if that's the case for OP though)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li class="class1">Hallo</li>
  <li class="class2">Hallo</li>
  <li>Hallo</li>
  <li class="class3">Hallo</li>
  <li>Hallo</li>
</ul>
```

This css, styles every li that has **no** class

```
li{
  color:blue;
}

li:not([class]) {
  color:red;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

For more information read [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#negation)

Comment: sorry i didnt mean to be rude. in your initial answer you just copied an answer from the duplicate question without even reading what it means. +after your edit, your answer is still incorrect...

Comment: your answer works, but is not correct. he wants to style elements which dont have any class at all, not a specific one.

Comment: much better now, +1 from me