# How to select one from a number of nodes in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

The following is HTML:

```
<div class="graph_tit" id="graph_tit">
<a href="/jsp/home/contents/climateData/smart/smartStatisticsSearch.do" class="on" onclick="return false;">관측자료</a> 
<a href="/jsp/home/contents/climateData/smart/smartStatisticsSearch.do" onclick="return false;" class="">통계자료</a> 
</div>
```

I want to select the second `a` element in CasperJS.

But, `<a>` nodes are similar.

The following is tried code in CasperJS.

```
$('div[id="graph_tit"] a[class=""]').click();

$('div[id="graph_tit"] a[text()="통계자료"]').click();
```

Comment: Which is the one and How do you want to select?

Comment: <a href="/jsp/home/contents/climateData/smart/smartStatisticsSearch.do" onclick="return false;" class="">통계자료</a>

Comment: If alexce's answer doesn't help you (and it should), then there is a problem somewhere else. Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf)). Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that the [`class` attribute is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353893/select-an-element-with-empty-class-attribute-class-using-css):

```
this.click('div.graph_tit a[class=""]');
```

You may also need to *wait for the selector*:

```
this.waitForSelector('div.graph_tit a[class=""]').thenClick('div.graph_tit a[class=""]');
```

Comment: Also, i use to waitForSelector.

Comment: error message : "Wait timeout of 5000ms expired, exiting."

Comment: @ARongKwon are there any iframe elements on a page?

Comment: I tried Chrome development. Chrome development is working well. But, CasperJS is not.

Comment: iframe exists on this page.

Comment: @ARongKwon good, then you need to switch to an iframe if the desired element is inside it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150194/how-do-i-access-an-iframe-from-casperjs.

Comment: When I think, A does not matter.

Comment: Because if iframe, Chrome development also must be bad.