# CSS hide a list element in a particular position

Tags: css

You closed this question because it seems duplicated, yet the answer has nothing to do with my question nor resolve my problem.

[Select an element with empty class attribute (class="") using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353893/select-an-element-with-empty-class-attribute-class-using-css)

I have a list in a website that I can't change the HTML, only the CSS, and I need to hide a list element that has no class or id.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="">
   <a href="description" data-toggle="tab">Descripción</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="">
   <a href="curriculum" data-toggle="tab">Currículum</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
   <a href="faq" data-toggle="tab" class="active">FAQ</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="">
   <a href="announcement" data-toggle="tab">Anuncio</a></li>
  <li role="presentation" class="">
   <a href="reviews" data-toggle="tab">Reseñas</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to hide the list element that contains the link FAQ. I know how to tackle the first and last element, yet not the 3rd element on a list. How could I do this?

Comment: are there other `<li>` tags in the HTML file ? (besides the ones shown)

Comment: Yep, they used <li> tags in several things like the nav menu